# How to use PrettyTime in time4j library?

Tags: android, kotlin, time, duration, time4j

I am receiving a text which is in seconds (e.g. 7261). I need to convert it to this format:
2h, 1m, 1s

I am using time4j library. According to their [Github page](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J), I am doing something like this:

```
val duration = Duration.of(7261, ClockUnit.SECONDS).with(Duration.STD_CLOCK_PERIOD)
val prettifiedDuration = PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).print(duration)
```

However, I get this error:

```
06-22 11:50:52.133 12161 12244 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-22 11:50:52.133 12161 12244 E AndroidRuntime:    at net.time4j.base.ResourceLoader.getInstance(ResourceLoader.java:167)
06-22 11:50:52.133 12161 12244 E AndroidRuntime:    at net.time4j.PrettyTime.<clinit>(PrettyTime.java:95)
06-22 11:50:52.133 12161 12244 E AndroidRuntime:    at net.time4j.PrettyTime.of(PrettyTime.java:198)
```

Any idea? or even, better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I realized there is a separate library for Android projects:
https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A

For Gradle, add this dependecy:

```
implementation("net.time4j:time4j-android:4.6-2020a")
```

And in your Application class, initialize the library:

```
class MyApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ApplicationStarter.initialize(this, true)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing some dependencies?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>time4j-base</artifactId>
        <version>5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>time4j-sqlxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>time4j-tzdata</artifactId>
        <version>5.0-2020a</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my tests, your code work fine.

```
val duration = Duration.of(7261, ClockUnit.SECONDS).with(Duration.STD_CLOCK_PERIOD)
val prettifiedDuration = PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).print(duration)

println(prettifiedDuration)
```

Output:

```
2 hours, 1 minute, and 1 second
```

Comment: Nope :) I actually realized there is a separate library for Android project which needs initialization